# Fancybox'ing a Handlebars template after using jQuery to grab data from codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm currently having an issue with loading a wizard I'm trying to make. When a user adds a project to their queue I create a new project in the database with the appropriate information. If that returns true then a js function is called to grab a Handlebars.js template, compile, and then push that into a Fancybox load. I pass data into this function to be used for the template, too.

It looks like this:

```
function launchProjectWizard(data)  {
        var source;
        var template;

        $.ajax({
            url : '/assets/templates/handlebars/projectWizard.handlebars',
            cache : true,
            dataType: "json",
            success : function(temp) {
                source = temp;
                template = Handlebars.compile(source);

                $.fancybox({
                    afterLoad : function() {
                        this.content = Handlebars.compile(this.template(JSON.parse(data)));
                    }
                }); //fancy
            }
        }); //ajax
    }
```

I'm not getting any errors currently. But nothing is happening, either. Fancybox isn't initiating, no error is thrown, nothing. The call before, that saves the project to the db, is working fine.

When I remove the "dataType" line, however, I do get Fancybox to fire off, but have the issue of it simply dumping the raw handlebars template in for its content, no compiling.

Is there an easier or better way to handle a modal wizard process in Codeigniter with these support technologies? Should I leave Handlebars out of it for this one?

Thanks for any assistance,

---

**EDIT 1:**
I'm getting this output in the console for my `data` object being passed into the function. Is Handlebars tripping up because of the `team` Array instead of Object? Yet it's not throwing any errors..

`Object {title: Object, team: Array[2], pid: 179}`

Comment: From a quick view, you are passing `temp` as parameter of `success` ... so where `data` is coming from (`JSON.parse(data)`)? ... shouldn't you parse `source`?

Comment: ... or since you are already doing `template = Handlebars.compile(source);` then try `$.fancybox(template)` only

Comment: jfk, `data` is being passed into the parent function from teh previous one, it is what holds the info that Handlebars should use to fill in my expressions. `temp` is just the big handlebars template itself

Comment: gave the (modified) suggestion, `$.fancybox(template(data))`, a try. no luck, still just the block from the external page. may be of interest: it is just dumped in, but without the expressions. so, instead of `<h3>{{OfferTitle}}</h3>` it's just `<h3></h3>`

Comment: added an edit above, check'r out

Comment: I don't think so. Why you don't do? before fancybox `var content = Handlebars.compile(this.template(JSON.parse(data)));` and then `$.fancybox(content);` ... just like that.

Comment: essentially the same thing as I tried above, but gave it a whirl anyway. still no luck. same issue: fancybox just having my external template dumped in, no compiling happening. think i may just nix the handlebars attempt here and make a CI controller to iFrame into fancybox